# canvas - Where do I put clearRect to refresh the animation?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm lost and could use a little help.

I am trying to get the apex of the curve to follow the mouse, but cannot find where I should refresh nor understand why.

```
function animate(){

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //c.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width,canvas.height);

    $( "#canvas" ).mousemove(function( event ) {

        topWave.draw(0, 300, event.pageX, 50,  $(window).width(), 300);

    });

}
```

Here is a codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpvaee

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Animation, rendering, and IO events.

1. You must separate the mouse events from the rendering as the mouse fires events at a different rate than the display is updated.
2. You should not query the DOM inside mouse or animation events. You should only query the DOM when you need to. At the start of the application, and when there are changes that will effect the state, such as resize events
3. `requestAnimationFrame` (rAF) is synced with the display rate (60 times a second). It does not matter where in the animation function you put rAF.
4. You render in order of visibility, background first then to the top most object last.
5. jQuery is slow, and 99.99% of the time it is easier to use the standard API. Try to avoid using jQuery, its an old dinosaur past its use by date. Using it is  preventing you from learning how best to use the DOM.

Thus from the points above your code should look more like. (with no jQuery)

```
// start the animation
requestAnimationFrame(animate); // this will fire when the setup code below has 
                                // has executed

// get the DOM object
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
// get the 2D context
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// create mouse object
const mouse = { x : 0, y : 0 };
// create mouse move event listener
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",(event) => {
    // each time mouse is moved update the mouse position
    mouse.x = event.clientX; 
    mouse.y = event.clientY;
});

// Via rAF this function is called once every 1/60 of a second.
// The rate may change if you do too much rendering, or is the browser is
// busy doing something else.
function animate(){
    
    // first thing to draw is the background, in this case that is clear
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // then draw your wave using the current mouse position
    // innerWidth (and innerHeight) is built in global value 
    // same as $("window").width() but a zillion times faster
    topWave.draw(0, 300, mouse.y, 50,  innerWidth, 300);

    // it does not matter where in this function you put rAF
    // I like to put it at the bottom of the function
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
```